# "Spanking brand new" or "Brand spanking new"?

Tags: idioms

What do you guys say? I've never heard **brand spanking new**, and yet that's the right expression according to the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

"Brand spanking new" is far more common, internet-wide and Google Books corpus-wide. Try the Google phrase searches, or [check out this ratio ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spanking%20brand%20new%2Fbrand%20spanking%20new&year_start=1800&year_end=2014&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28spanking%20brand%20new%20/%20brand%20spanking%20new%29%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C(spanking%20brand%20new%20%2F%20brand%20spanking%20new)%3B%2Cc0). However, the usage of the alternative is sufficient to conclude that it's a genuinely attested phrase not simply an error of usage - and the ratio used to be closer than it is now.

It's just **brand new** with *spanking* used as an emphatic. Note that this is an idiom; *spanking* is not generally an emphatic. As such, it makes sense either way.

Comment: I have never heard any order except "brand spanking new".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I have, on occasion, and there are clearly people out there using it. I'm not in a position to judge if it's a dialect thing.

Comment: Since it is casual and verging on dialect, I, too would hesitate to dismiss "spanking brand new" out of hand. The phrase is the title of a song by Joan Armatrading, and it is found in lots of casual web sources, (Trip advisor, Twitter) from all over the Anglosphere. I suspect that "brand spanking new" is the "dictionary" version.